# How to unload select2 script/styles loaded by new WooCommerce 2.3.x?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

we are theme developers and we already use select2 (http://select2.github.io/) script for SELECT boxes in HTML in our wordpress theme.
New WooCommerce 2.3.x that just relased now use select2 scripts too. But they override its styles with its own (most of all with !important tags) in many different ways.

We can't redeclare all of their CSS changes with !important rules, this will be a lot of CSS mess that we don't like. Also now our JS script loaded 2 times and conflicts sometimes too (because woocommerce loads its own select2 js).

My question is what is a best way to deactivate woocommerce select2 CSS and JS files in our theme functions? We want to use our script version and our styles file (for woocommerce select elements too).

I tryed to use wp_dequeue_script, wp_deregister_script and the same functions available for styles, but this does not help. As I see woocommerce add scripts/css AFTER our theme already initialized and we can't deactivate it.

Thanks.

This is code that loaded in /includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php that I need to disable from theme functions:

```
self::register_script( 'select2', $assets_path . 'js/select2/select2' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.5.2' );
self::enqueue_script( 'select2' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'select2', $assets_path . 'css/select2.css' );
```

How to unload this CSS/JS files in theme functions, without changing original WooCommerce files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mgt_dequeue_stylesandscripts', 100 );

function mgt_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'select2' );

        wp_dequeue_script( 'select2');
        wp_deregister_script('select2');

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There's been some recent changes to WooCommerce (v 3.2.1) in which they forked the select2 script and so the code above by @Dmitry is no longer functional.  The new code which worked for me is below..

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts', 100 );

function agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'selectWoo' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'selectWoo' );

    wp_dequeue_script( 'selectWoo');
    wp_deregister_script('selectWoo');

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting a duplication of the select fields. There appears to be an issue due to Woocommerce making a call to:

```
?wc-ajax=update_order_review
```

after the page is loaded, which then introduces a **select2** element just after each select element:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container ... >
```

This span appears under the dropdown and contains the currently chosen option.

[Duplicate dropdown element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsJ3V.png)

I tried adding `wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );` to his code, which did stop the span from appearing, but also stopped other functionality, which was needed.

In the end, I hid the span with css:

```
.woocommerce-checkout .select2-container {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a gist that might help or provide a way forward : https://gist.github.com/gregrickaby/2846416

Also have a look at `includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php` to see how the scripts are being enqueued.

I have copied the code pasted below from the following URL which shows how to dequeue individual styles, which may also help : http://docs.woothemes.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/

```
// Remove each style one by one
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );
function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] ); // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] ); // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] ); // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this filter allow only to disable this 3 kind of styles (general, layout and smallscreen) and does not allow to disable any other CSS file that loaded by WooCommerce. There are no other filters available in WooCommerce at includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php. I added code to my original post, what I need to disable.