# Universal css to fix double border in dropdown menu

Tags: css, html

Is there a universal way of fixing this issue?

[image: Double border problem]

This is what my chrome dev has for me when I choose the first problematic field.

```css
element.style {
    width: 499px;
}
.woocommerce form .form-row.woocommerce-validated .select2-container, .woocommerce form .form-row.woocommerce-validated input.input-text, .woocommerce form .form-row.woocommerce-validated select {
    border-color: #69bf29;
}

.woocommerce form .form-row .select2-container, .select2-container .select2-selection--single, .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
    min-height: 2.40741rem;
}
.woocommerce form .form-row .select2-container {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2em;
}
.select2-container--default {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px 0 0;
}
.select2-container--default, .woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper input {
    border: 1px solid #1F2A5C!important;
}
.select2-container {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
*, .col-xs, .gridContainer, .row {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
*, .col-xs, .gridContainer, .row {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
span[Attributes Style] {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
```

Comment: May or may not be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547598/how-to-unload-select2-script-styles-loaded-by-new-woocommerce-2-3-x . Anyway, anyone who can solve this from that CSS and that linked image and haven't seen this exact problem before, is a bloody magician.